# MySQL Query to find monthly active user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  account_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time_start datetime NOT NULL,
  time_end datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (account_id),
  KEY idx_start (account_id,time_start),
  KEY idx_end (account_id,time_end)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

How can I write a query to find how many users log on monthly?

I want to find for the last 90 days how many different account_id are in the table group by month. Group by month means here every 30 days: for example from 2011-12-05 to 2011-11-06, from 2011-12-04 to 2011-11-05 and so on for the last 90 days.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially get years/months out of a datetime field with `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` respectively. But your periods don't match start/end on month boundaries, so you'll need some ugly-looking query logic to handle that conversion.

You should start by writing a [stored function/procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) that'll convert a regular date/time to a "fiscal" date time, after which the query should become much cleaner looking. Once you've got the procedure done, it can be reused everywhere, as fiscal period calculations will undoubtedly be repeated elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

This query assumes two things:
1) you have your month logic squared-away (see @Marc's post) and added as an extra column (month) on the table.
2) time_start is the time that the user has "logged-on".

```
SELECT COUNT(*), month
FROM account
GROUP BY month
HAVING time_start > ADDDATE(CURDATE(),- INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Try messing around with it and see if that helps.  I'm not too sure on the negative ADDDATE bit there, so you'll want to check-out MySQL's reference page for [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Clearly the answer is correct. However, SOF shouldn't be a place where everyone come to be spoon-fed. Besides, this question is obvious duplicate and been asked hundreds of times already. Instead, you should have reported a duplicate.

Comment: @Guy I didn't give him the whole answer.  I gave him a starting point to "mess around with" as well as a reference to look-up himself.  Just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(distinct account_id)
from account
where 
time_start >= date_sub(now(), interval 90 day)
group by
floor(datediff(now(), time_start) / 30)
```